# printing ggplot with purrr map

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

I want to create `ggplots` for `numeric cols` against my `response variable`.

Here is the reproducible code:

```r
test = mpg %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
dplyr::select(-year) %>% nest(-cyl) %>% 
mutate(ggplots = map(data,~ggplot(data = .x) + geom_point(aes(x = cyl, y = .x))))

test
# A tibble: 4 x 3
    cyl           data ggplots
  <int> <list<df[,3]>> <list> 
1     4       [81 x 3] <gg>   
2     6       [79 x 3] <gg>   
3     8       [70 x 3] <gg>   
4     5        [4 x 3] <gg>   
Warning message:
All elements of `...` must be named.
Did you want `data = c(displ, cty, hwy)`?
```

Getting the error:

```r
test$ggplots[[1]]
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type tbl_df/tbl/data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (81): x, y
```

whats wrong?

Comment: You have `data=.x` and `aes(y=.x)`. One of those `.x` needs to be a data.frame/tibble and the other needs to be a column name. What are you trying to plot exactly?

Comment: trying to plot `cyl` against all the other `numeric cols`

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't want any plots by groups but instead are looking for `cyl` plotted against other variables?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option when we want to loop through a bunch of variables and plot each of them against another variable is to loop through the variable names.

I would first pull out the variable names I want on the `y`.  I use `set_names()` at the end of the pipe to name the vector with itself, because sometimes I need that for organization later.

```
vars = mpg %>%
     select_if(is.numeric) %>%
     select(-cyl, - year) %>%
     names() %>%
     set_names()
```

The result is a vector of strings.

```
vars
# displ     cty     hwy 
# "displ"   "cty"   "hwy"
```

Now I can loop through those variable names and make a plot against the fixed `x` variable `cyl`.  I'll use a `purrr::map()` loop for this.  Since I'm working with strings I need to use tidy evaluation within `ggplot()`, done with the `.data` pronoun (I believe this only works since the latest 0.4.0 release of **rlang**).  I label the y axis with the variable in `labs()`, otherwise it has the `.data` pronoun in the axis label.

```
plots = map(vars, ~ggplot(data = mpg) +
                 geom_point(aes(x = cyl, y = .data[[.x]]) ) +
                 labs(y = .x)
)
```

I demonstrate the approach above [in a blog post I wrote last year](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/08/20/automating-exploratory-plots/) if you're interested in more explanation.

If you don't want to loop through strings like this, another option is to reshape the dataset into a long format and then use the nesting approach.  The idea is to make a long dataset, taking the variables you want on the y axis and putting their values all together in a single column.  I do this with `tidyr::pivot_longer()`.    The numeric values for the `y` variables are now in a single column, named `value`.

Then nest the `cyl` and `value` columns for each variable name.  Once that is done you'll have a three row dataset, one row per `y` variable, and you can loop through the datasets in `mutate()` to create your column of plots as in your original attempt.

```
plots2 = mpg %>%
     select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
     dplyr::select(-year) %>% 
     pivot_longer(cols = -cyl) %>% 
     nest(data = -name) %>%
     mutate(ggplots = map(data, 
                          ~ggplot(data = .x) + geom_point(aes(x = cyl, y = value)))
```

Comment: what is this sorcery :D amazing my friend :)